# Publishing forms to a particular user

Tags: formsflow.ai, formsflow

Will the designer be able to publish forms to  a particular user(client)?Because now if he/she publish forms, it can be view by all users with client access na?

Answer (score 0):

No we cannot publish a form only to a particular client using the designer page in formsflow.ai  as of now. However we.can customise the code to check the group access and show the forms list to the users belonging to that particular group in Keycloak. We will be doing more refining as part of Multitenancy feature we will bring in future release.